# Word for "scheduled activities"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I mentally checked my [...], but realized I had none.

The only word I can think of is *agenda*. But, I don't know, it sounds strange. Maybe it's because *agenda* is sounds more like the place where you put the activities and not the activities themselves.

Comment: calendar, schedule

Comment: Generally, it wouldn't be said the way you propose in your example, even if a single word were found to fit. A more likely statement might be something like "I checked my *schedule* AND (*not BUT)* realized I had no *plans*. Also, a subtle problem with the form you offered is that you can't check something that doesn't exist. You can have a schedule or an agenda that is empty, but you can't have a something that doesn't exist (even if it's mental).

Comment: In GB I believe they check their "diary", which sounds odd to me, in the US who refer to that same item as a "daytimer" (actually a brand of organizer books), or as already mentioned, "calendar" or "schedule".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Itinerary? I'm not sure if the definition would work for what you have in mind but maybe this is what you are thinking of?

Comment: perhaps it wouldbe best if you would include a definition of the word. :) n

Answer (score 2):

[Program](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/program) may fit :

> - a schedule of activities, procedures, etc., to be followed.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: An organized event, such as a conference, might have a program. However, it would be odd to say that somebody has a program.

Comment: @200_success -    "What's your program today? I have a few meetings and a business lunch."  Sounds ok to my ears.

Answer (score 2):

If "**none**" means "**meetings**", try : **[rendezvous](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rendezvous)**

- (n) a meeting planned at a certain time and place
- a date; usually with a member of the opposite sex

Comment: Sorry, Mysti, IMO, that's just not something a native speaker would say.  I also think there's something missing from OP's example..."I mentally checked of my ..." is not grammatical.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, I agree, the sentence is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use **commitments**:

> **Commitment** : something that you must do or deal with that takes your time:
>   family/work commitments I've got too many commitments at the moment to
>   do an evening class. Children are such a commitment. - *[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/commitment)*
>
> **Commitment**: An engagement or obligation that restricts freedom of action: with so
>   many business commitments time for recreation was limited - *[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commitment)*

But I've not found this definition in all online dictionaries. Is it a UK thing, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

"I mentally checked my [to-do list](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to-do-list), but..."

> **Noun**
>
> A list of tasks that need to be completed, typically organized in order of priority:
>    ‘social security reform was at the top of the president’s to-do list’
>
> *www.oxforddictionaries.com*

Comment: +1..that's what a layman like me thinks of : a to-do-list

Answer (score 1):

In British English, "diary", but I don't believe that Americans use the word in that way.

Comment: Indeed, Americans think of a diary as more of a log of past events (and especially your personal thoughts about them) than a plan of future events. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diary

Comment: It has that meaning in BE as well, alongside the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

*Agenda* is perfectly acceptable here. You're right, the place where plans are recorded can be referred to as an agenda. However, someone's unrecorded plans can also be referred to as their agenda. The book containing plans is called an agenda because it contains an agenda.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agenda
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/agenda

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking a physical (or digital) record, use the word [**planner**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/planner?s=t). It's similar to agenda without the double meaning

> 2.
>   a book, similar to a desk calendar, for recording appointments, things to be done, etc.

Otherwise, use **schedule** or **timetable**

Schedule

> 1.
>   a plan of procedure, usually written, for a proposed objective, especially with reference to the sequence of and time allotted for each item or operation necessary to its completion.
>
> 2.
>   a series of things to be done or of events to occur at or during a particular 
>   time or period:

Timetable

> 2. any schedule or plan designating the times at or within which certain things occur or are scheduled to occur

<sup>All definitions from dictionary.com</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think that [plan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plan) can be used here

> something that a person intends to do

It fits in your example : I mentally checked my plan, but realized I had none.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly **appointments**

> 2. An arrangement to do something or meet someone at a particular time and place.

(thefreedictionary.com)

Answer (score -2):

Could you just use the word 'schedule' and modify the rest of the sentence.

A 'schedule' is a list of events occurring at set times.

> I mentally checked my schedule, but realized I didn't have one.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to post under this question. It's great that you want to help. However, this answer doesn't really seem to be a full answer. When answering it's best, in the case of [tag:single-word-requests], to give a good explanation why the word you're suggesting is a good one. If necessary quote and reference a dictionary.